# Ionic accordion dropdown open and close

Tags: angular, ionic4

I had created ionic accordion dropdown menus by following a tutorial blog link which used widgets for creating an accordion dropdowns, Below is the link of that blog.
http://masteringionic.com/blog/2019-01-27-creating-a-simple-accordion-widget-in-ionic-4/

Below is the my project link which i uploaded in github 
https://stackblitz.com/github/dSaif/search-accordion

Everything is working fine but i want the toggle dropdown(open dropdown need to gets closed automatically when i open any other drop down menu on click to the icon provided)

Please help me how can i do this as iam newbie to ionic and angular.

thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The way you have set it up is that you have a bunch of `<app-accordion>` in your document like:

```
<app-accordion></app-accordion>
<app-accordion></app-accordion>
<app-accordion></app-accordion>
<app-accordion></app-accordion>
<app-accordion></app-accordion>
<app-accordion></app-accordion>
```

It can't know what its neighbour is doing, but it doesn't need to, because the best practice is to define the bottom-most components to be as "dumb" as possible.

What you need is an `@Input` property for the `isMenuOpen` that you already have. And then in a parent component you keep a list of bools, one for each accordion item.

```
  <app-accordion
     *ngFor="let technology of technologies; let i = index"
     [isMenuOpen]="isMenuOpen[i].isOpen"
     [name]="technology.name"
     [description]="technology.description"
     [image]="technology.image"
     (change)="captureName($event)"></app-accordion>
```

You should really rename your `app-accordion` to `app-accordion-item` and then make a new wrapper component `app-accordion` which can manage this.

Notice that I also improved the way your Input variables are being set to make them [] one way databound instead of using the interpolation method you were using before.

I also added `let i = index` which is an Angular feature to get the index of the loop, so you can get the right item in the `isMenuOpen` array.

So how does `isMenuOpen` keep up to date? Well you need a to write another `@Output` for the accordion-item to emit each toggle, with its index and its status, and then you can update the `isMenuOpen` array.

So this meets our original intention, because the bottom level accordion item doesnt really know anything about the state, it just displays the open or closed that you tell it to from above, and then announces when it gets toggled itself, but leaves the storing of information up to the parent accordion component.

Comment: hi @rtpHarry, thank you for your answer. really appreciate your time and patience.  I tried making changes as you updated but its now allowing to rename 'app-accordion' to 'app-accordion-item'. can you please make changes in my stackblitz code and send it to me. thank you

Comment: Please consider upvoting if it helped. I will try to make the changes this evening after work.

Comment: I've done some research and [Josh's accordion tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-accordion-list-in-ionic/) covers the concepts that I touched on in my answer. His "expandable component" is what i describe as "accordion-item". For the actual accordion he just implements it into the homepage, but I would make another component so that you can re-use it in different places and keep the logic encapsulated.

Comment: If you look near the end you will see how he tracks the open item and closes all the others, just search for `expandItem` in the tutorial.